# Creating a generic for-loop that'll print the user input into a grid-like object

Tags: c#, for-loop

Assignment for game design using the Microsoft C# tutorial as a basis

[image]

Display to console

- the value held by `number1` in a grid
- with `number2` amount of rows
- and `number3` amount of columns.

Something like "If num1 is 8 * row = 4 and column = 5"
I'm sorry I'm just beginning to learn this.

```cs
for (int row = number2; row < number1; row++)
{
    for (int column = number3; column <= number1; column++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{row}{column}");
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to get a good answer you should try to accomplish this yourself and then if you run into any issues, post those. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you pls provide the output in a bit more detail. I can't deduce the outcome you are looking for.

Comment: "*plz no bully*" no one bullys here, However, we do require you to give sufficient information when asking a question to make it very clear. A question like this would be answered in minutes if you can add the right information and make your self clear

Comment: Further more, using `number1`, `number2`, `number1` is a little confusing, also, give an example of input, and the desired output

Comment: What I'm basically trying to do is to print a grid of numbers using user input. Num1 is the number that'll be printed, num2 is how many rows they'll be, and num3 is how many columns they'll be. I've tried switching up the Var placements but it hasn't given me the result I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment description

> What I'm basically trying to do is to print a grid of numbers using
> user input. Num1 is the number that'll be printed, num2 is how many
> rows they'll be, and num3 is how many columns they'll be. I've tried
> switching up the Var placements but it hasn't given me the result I
> prefer.

Potentially, this might be what you are looking for

```
var charToPrint = 'x';

var rows = 5;
var columns = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      Console.Write(charToPrint); // writes character at a time for each column
   Console.WriteLine();  // write a new line for end of row
}
```

**Output**

```
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j8PqKp)

---

Another way might be using `Enumerable.Range`, `Select`, `string.Join` and the string *constructor*

```
var result = Enumerable
   .Range(1, rows)
   .Select(x => new string(charToPrint,columns));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,result));
```

To do the input validation you could do something like this

```
var input = string.Empty;
var rows = 5;
var columns = 4;

Console.WriteLine("Enter character to print");
while ((input = Console.ReadLine()).Length != 1)
   Console.WriteLine("you had one job! Enter character to print");

var charToPrint = input[0];

Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of rows");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out rows))
   Console.WriteLine("you had one job! Enter the number of rows");


Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of columns");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out columns))
   Console.WriteLine("you had one job! Enter the number of columns");
```

**Example output**

```
Enter character to print
23423
you had one job! Enter character to print
d
Enter the number of rows
d
you had one job! Enter the number of rows
5
Enter the number of columns
4
dddd
dddd
dddd
dddd
dddd
```

Answer (score 0):

It was this..

```
for(int row = 0; row < number2; row++)
{
  for(int column = 0; column < number3; column++)
  {
    Console.Write(number1);// once it prints number1
  }
  Console.WriteLine();// it goes to next line
}
```